# Put scraped data into an html file (Python3)

Tags: python, html, iteration

I am creating a script that will:
1. scrape data from a local company's website news section. (news date, news headline & article link)
2. take this information and put them in specific places in a webpage (html file) to be displayed elsewhere. (by reading a file, and copying the file line by line, replacing keywords with scraped data.. perhaps this is not the best method; if so let me knoiw

I already managed to complete the first part (scraping) but am facing difficulties imagining how I am going to put it in the html file. for now I was trying to copy the html file but replace.

It is obvious to me that either (or both) my method and/or the location where it get's called need to be altered.

Also it might add value to mention that there are 10 news headlines, which all 10 I want to put in the other html file (Which for now, is a very standard html table, see below python code)

*my python3 code:*

```
#import requirements
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import urllib.request
import re


def CopyAndAdapt(datum="datum", headline="headline", link="link"):
    fin = open("input.html", "rt")
    fout = open("outputfile.html", "wt")
    counter = 1
    for line in fin:
        if counter > 3:
            counter = 1
        if '@' not in line:
            fout.write(line)
        elif '@' in line:
            if counter == 1:
                fout.write(line.replace('@'+str(counter), datum))
            if counter == 2:
                fout.write(line.replace('@'+str(counter), headline))
            if counter == 3:
                fout.write(line.replace('@'+str(counter), link))

    fin.close()
    fout.close()

# set values
the_url = '[redacted]'
base_url = '[redacted]'
html_output_file = "testpagina.html"


# get&interpret html
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

# select the unordered list named link-list bigger
section = soup.find('ul', class_='link-list bigger')

# select all list items in $section
subsections = section.find_all('li')

# for each news item in the news section performs actions described in comments.
for subsection in subsections:

    # selects href from single news headline, concatenates it with base-url.
    news_link = base_url + subsection.a.get('href')

    # selects text part from single news headline, strips empty white spaces before and after
    stripped_text = subsection.text.strip()

    # seperates release-date from headline for a single news headline
    news_date = stripped_text[0:5]
    news_headline = stripped_text[5:]

    #CopyAndAdapt(news_date,news_headline,news_link)
```

Target HTML document (locations where data should be stored is marked as @1 @2 @3 for (1:date 2:headlinetext 3:link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>@1</th>
    <th>@2</th>
    <th>@3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>@1</td>
    <td>@2</td>
    <td>@3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I would advise you to use the `with open(filename) as file:` syntax to manage your files, instead of `open` then `close`.

Comment: thanks, i know of this feature. there are a few more things in the code that could be improved; but overall functionality is my main goal now  (such as an unused import re)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JINJA2 in you project to generate the HTML (if you're not using a framework, otherwise the framework already has a template engine).

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/

https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/?highlight=templatestream#jinja2.environment.TemplateStream

I'd refactor your code to something like:

```
#import requirements
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import urllib.request
import re
import jinja2


# set values
the_url = '[redacted]'
base_url = '[redacted]'
html_output_file = "testpagina.html"


# get&interpret html
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

# select the unordered list named link-list bigger
section = soup.find('ul', class_='link-list bigger')

# select all list items in $section
subsections = section.find_all('li')

items = []
# for each news item in the news section performs actions described in comments.
for subsection in subsections:

    # selects href from single news headline, concatenates it with base-url.
    news_link = base_url + subsection.a.get('href')

    # selects text part from single news headline, strips empty white spaces before and after
    stripped_text = subsection.text.strip()

    # seperates release-date from headline for a single news headline
    news_date = stripped_text[0:5]
    news_headline = stripped_text[5:]

    # create dict to use in template and append
    item = {}
    item['datum'] = news_date
    item['headline'] = news_headline
    item['link'] = news_link
    items.append(item)

jinja2.Template("""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>HTML Table</h2>
        <table>
        {%for item in items %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ item.datum }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.headline }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.link }}</td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
    """).stream(items=items).dump('hello.html')
```

To clarify my changes:

Removed **CopyAndAdapt()** function (i think you were trying to create your HTML here)

Added the following lines:

```
import jinja2

items = []

# create dict to use in template and append
item = {}
item['datum'] = news_date
item['headline'] = news_headline
item['link'] = news_link
items.append(item)


jinja2.Template("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    <table>
      {%for item in items %}
      <tr>
      <td>{{ item.datum }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.headline }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.link }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
""").stream(items=items).dump('hello.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query correctly:

- You would like to retrieve, from a news website, every news date, title and url
- Then, you would like to put it into an HTML page, as a table.

You've already done the webscraping.

I would suggest your script does this:

- Init a html content string with headers and the start of your table
- Do the webscraping
- For each news you find

  - Retrieve the data you seek: date, title, utl
  - Append to your content string the table row with this data
- Finish your content string by closing your table and putting footers
- Write this content string into an html file

This can be achieved in bash or python, and probably other languages.

If your html page is meant to be more complex, you can also only create the table as a string, and append it to HTML header and footer files, or replace a single tag into an all inclusive HTML file (with CSS etc).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested, and to future readers, this is how I ended up making it work (nevertheless Laurent C. and Henrique Goncalves have both given highly valuable and applicable answers! Much appreciation to them both!)

my eventual code:

```
#import requirements
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import urllib.request
import re


def ReplaceInFile(counter, tableRow):
    if counter > 0:
        fin = open("outputfile.html", "rt")
    elif counter == 0:
        fin = open("input.html", "rt")
    data = fin.read()
    data = data.replace('@'+str(counter), tableRow)
    fin.close()

    fin = open("outputfile.html", "wt")
    fin.write(data)
    fin.close()

# set values
the_url = '[redacted]'
base_url = '[redacted]'
html_output_file = "testpagina.html"


# get&interpret html
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(the_url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce, 'lxml')

# select the unordered list named link-list bigger
section = soup.find('ul', class_='link-list bigger')

# select all list items in $section
subsections = section.find_all('li')

#create start of table
table_start = "<h2>HTML Table</h2>\n<table>"

# for each news item in the news section performs actions described in comments.
counter = 0
for subsection in subsections:

    # selects href from single news headline, concatenates it with base-url.
    news_link = base_url + subsection.a.get('href')

    # selects text part from single news headline, strips empty white spaces before and after
    stripped_text = subsection.text.strip()

    # seperates release-date from headline for a single news headline
    news_date = stripped_text[0:5]
    news_headline = stripped_text[5:]

    #create row for table from single news subject
    table_row = "<tr>\n    <th>"+news_date+"</th>\n    <th>"+news_headline+"</th>\n    <th>"+news_link+"</th>\n  </tr>"

    ReplaceInFile(counter, table_row)
    counter = counter + 1
```